# How to get first and second derivative matrix of an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gaussian

I am trying to compute the gradient orientation of an image, in the first part, I need to compute the first-order derivative of an image (in both horizontal and vertical direction), so I applied Gaussian filter in scipy module in order to get it, but I got an error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'"

I am using python version 3.7.0 and the opencv version is 3.4.2.

The function documentation is here:[scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/SciPyPackages/Ndimage.html)

```py
g_x = np.zeros(image_new.shape) 
ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(image_new, 2*np.sqrt(2), (0,1), 1 ,g_x )
```

Is this correct? or how to compute the first derivative(and second derivative) of an image.

Comment: Your link it to an archival dump of old wiki content --- see [scipy.org](http://scipy.org/) for current material. Can you edit your question to include the version of python, and opencv you are using?

Comment: I just edited my question! Thx

Comment: See https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html for sobel_h for the x derivative and sobel_v for the y derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first derivative of the image, you can apply gaussian filter in scipy as follows.

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter, laplace

image_first_derivative = gaussian_filer(image, sigma=3)
```

If sigma is a single number, then derrivative will calculated in all directions. To specify the direction pass the sigma as sequence.

[image: x-direction with sigma = (11, 0)]

Above is the first derivative of the image taken in x-direction with `sigma=(11,0)`. The below image is derivative taken in y-direction with `sigma=(0, 11)`

[image: y-direction with sigma = (0, 11)]
you can choose the value of sigma accordingly. For calculating second derivative laplacian operator can be used.

```
image_sec_derivative = laplace(image)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to compute the first derivative in the horizontal or vertical direction?